# Google calendar API push notifications - update from API creates unnecessary notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

I have a rails app using Google calendar API with push notifications for each calendar the user shares with my app.

when user updates an event from app, it creates an `updatedEvent` request to API.
because the calendar is listed to push notification, it pushes a notification about some update to the calendar events (the same event of course ).
am i missing an attribute that can silent the notify?

when i get notify about changes and get the changed items from response,  i compare the `etag` of the event with the one that i get from the API response so i manged to avoid another update.

but it's still an unnecessary update.

Comment: I don't think you can silent the notification. Push notification informs your application when there is a change to the resource. Whenever a watched resource changes, your application will receive a notification message describing the change. The Google Calendar API sends these messages as HTTPS POST requests to the URL you specified as the "address" for this notification channel. Let me know if your question is different from this.

Comment: i am aware of how Google Calendar API way of push notifications works , it's just odd that my app sends the update for an event, and then gets notified about this event, it really doesn't solve the hole unnecessary polling for changes.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to filter out messages for one specific application for specific updates. Also you need to understand that if your app changes something then push needs to be delivered to all other apps which would otherwise not sync the change you just made.